# How to cover a test class to test Account ID = Null

Tags: apex, unit-test, test-automation

I need a help in covering the Account ID = Null please find my test class below.

```
static testMethod void DevelopmentRequestFormControllerNegativeTest() {
     Test.startTest();
    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];
    User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='samuel.robert2@peoplenet.com',EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
                      LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id,TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='samuel.robert2@peoplenet.com'); 

    System.RunAs(u){

        Account account = new Account(name='Tester');
        account.BillingState = 'GA';                    
        account.BillingPostalCode = '30340';   
        account.Type = 'Customer';
        insert account;          
        ApexPages.StandardController standControl = new ApexPages.standardController(account);

        Account group0 = new Account(ParentId = account.Id, Name = 'test group account 0', BillingPostalCode = '30340', Type = 'GROUP-PNET');
        group0.BillingState = 'GA';                    
        group0.BillingPostalCode = '30340';        
        insert group0;

        System.PageReference pr = ApexPages.currentPage();
        Map<String, String> test  =pr.getParameters();
        test.put('', account.Id);

        DevelopmentRequestFormController rf = new DevelopmentRequestFormController();
        Attachment rfAttachment = new Attachment();
        rfAttachment.Name = 'Unit Test';
        rfAttachment.Body  = Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Body');
        rf.attachment = rfAttachment;
        rf.accountId = account.Id;
        rf.Name = '';
        rf.BenefittoOrganization = '';
        rf.ChangeImpact='';
        rf.ContactNumber = '';
        rf.EmailAddress = '';
        rf.Enhancedreportname = '';
        rf.Problem = '';
        rf.Title = '';
        rf.TimeSensitivity = '';
        rf.ProposedChange = '';
        Date RequestDate = Date.newInstance(2016, 09, 23);
        rf.mail_attach_yes_no = 'Yes';
        rf.parentId = '';
        rf.submit();
        rf.updateAccountInformation();

}
      Test.stopTest();
```

}

Code that Iam trying to cover.

```
try{ 
            Id CID = Id.valueOf(SID);
            accountId = CID;
            List<Account> accs = [select Id,name from Account where Id =: CID];
            if(accs!=null && !accs.isEmpty())
            {
                prf.Account__c = accs.get(0).Id;
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'The URL is valid to create forms, please follow to fill the required information'));  
                validURL = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'The link you are using is not valid Please contact our sales Department at 1-800-434-9517 ' ));  
                validURL = false;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {      
            System.debug('Line Number is = '+ex.getLineNumber()+' Message is = ' +ex.getMessage());
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'The link you are using is not valid Please contact our sales Department at 1-800-434-9517' ));  
            validURL = false;
        }
    }
```

Iam tryiing to cover the code especially after "else"

Comment: are you throwing any exceptions from controller method when AccountId is null? If so, you can catch the exception and check the message in test class

Comment: It might help if you included the relevant portions of the code that you're trying to get coverage for. Have you tried commenting out the line where you set the account id as a page parameter?

Comment: @derek I have now included the piece of code that iam trying to cover.

Comment: @SamuelRobert That helps. However, once again, have you tried commenting out the line where you set the account id as a page parameter?

Comment: @Derek I did tried commenting it still I was unable to cover the code, I think I should find way to make rf.accountId to be null so that it may get covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main logic is faulty, and will throw exceptions for no good reason.

Instead, your code should probably look like this:

```
if(validUrl = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Account WHERE Id = :sid] == 1) {
    prf.Account__c = sid;
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'The URL is valid to create forms, please follow to fill the required information'));  
} else {
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'The link you are using is not valid Please contact our sales Department at 1-800-434-9517 ' ));  
}
```

There's no try-catch block required, and the entire code is simplified.

As for actually getting to the else block, you just need to give your page an invalid Id, probably by faking it. You haven't mentioned where "sid" is coming from, but you just need to put in an invalid Id, such as 001000000000001, or possibly even just "Hello World."

Comment: @SamuelRobert You're welcome. It's usually better to optimize than to try to unit test overly verbose code, so long as the core logic remains valid. I actually found one more optimization while I was in the shower, reducing the entire code down to just six lines.